# Как при клике на элемент поменять его класс?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такой вот код:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(e) {
  var child = $("#" + $(this).val());
  child.removeClass('text-left text-danger').addClass('text-left text-success');
});
```

этот код при выборе радиобаттона меняет в нем класс, сначала удаляя и тут же проставляя другой.

Так вот, нужно доработать этот код так, чтобы при клике на радиобаттон, до того как произойдет замена класса, выбранный и активный до этого радиобаттон также менял свой класс только в обратном порядке, т.е. при клике на радиобаттон меняется `text-left text-danger` на `text-left text-success`, а выбранный до этого радиобаттон нужно поменять `text-left text-success` на `text-left text-danger`.

Comment: В чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: А вы прочитайте, что написано на стрелке вниз - *"Данный вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несет пользы"* ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(e) {
  $("input[type=radio]").removeClass("text-success");
  $("input[type=radio]").addClass("text-danger");
  $(this).removeClass('text-danger').addClass('text-success');
});
```

```css
.text-success+b {
  color: green;
}
.text-danger+b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" class="text-left text-danger"><b>radio1</b>
<input type="radio" name="test" class="text-left text-danger"><b>radio2</b>
<input type="radio" name="test" class="text-left text-success" checked><b>radio3</b>
```

Comment: Благодарю!!! Ваше решение работает, ура! :)

Answer (score 2):

Для решения нужно выбрать элемент, который уже активен, у него будет класс *text-success*, и применить к нему и текущему элементу метод [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(e) {
  var child = $("#" + $(this).val());
  $("input[type=radio].text-success").add(child).toggleClass('text-danger text-success');
});
```